# A palavra "tchuco" em Cabo Verde veio, de alguma forma, do português?

Tags: etimologia, cabo-verde

Em Cabo Verde, a palavra *tchuco* (ou *tchuque*) significa *porco*. Na minha experiência, quase todas as palavras do crioulo cabo-verdiano tem origem noutras palavras do português. Mas não estou a conseguir encontrar nenhuma palavra parecida com "tchuco" que tem a ver com porcos. Qual foi a origem desta palavra? Tem algum cognato no português?

Comment: A título de curiosidade, existe algum recurso online (dicionário) onde se possa consultar palavras do Crioulo Cabo-Verdiano?

Comment: @gmauch não sei se existe. Sei que existe alguns listas de palavras, por exemplo [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_Swadesh_-_Crioulo_cabo-verdiano). Ao nível dos dicionários do português não. O crioulo é muito mais falado do que escrito, tem vários dialetos, e nunca foi regularizada a escritura das palavras.

Comment: Andei à procura e nada achei. *Tchuco* é crioulo de Santo Antão e S. Vicente; em vária outras ilhas é *porco*. O som /ʃ/ do português tende a dar /tʃ/ no crioulo (*macho* > *matcho*), mas *chuco* também não se parece obviamente com nada em português. Para além de termos globais, *porco, suíno, leitão, bácoro*, encontrei regionalismos: *larego,  cevado, reco, marrano, corrucho, tó, cochino* (do castelhano) no centro e norte de Portugal; *barrasco (reprodutor), suvão* no sul; *caitibu, queixada (selvagens) e cachaço* no Brasil.

Comment: De acordo com o Priberam, [*chico*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/chico) pode significar *porco*, e foi fonte da palavra [*chiqueiro*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/chiqueiro). Agora não sei se *chico* virou *tchuco*. Parece-me um bocadinho difícil, visto que o «i» é tónico. Houve tendência para «e» ou «i» *atónico* (/ɨ/) virar [u] ou [a]. Na S. Vicente, *chiqueiro* é *chiqueir*; tem /i/, não /u/.

Comment: Acho que *chico* é a melhor hipótese. *Chiqueiro dos porcos* (não *chiqueiro dos chicos*) aparece num dicionário de 1562.

Comment: interessante, a palavra tchuco na região sul do Brasil pode significar bebado

Comment: tchuco, pelo menos no Sul do Brasil, é gíria para bêbado. Poderia dizer: bebi tanto ontem que fiquei tchuco. (http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/tchuco/). Segundo esse site (http://bemfalar.com/significado/tchuque.html) é um regionalismo de Cabo Verde. Não sei se tem uma palavra parecida em português.

Comment: Uma referência neste artigo https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/43576044.pdf, tchuco como "texugo" de "Estás gordo como um texugo".

Comment: @sumitani interessante. Sim, no crioulo de São Vicente, -ugo, -uco, e -uque têm a mesma pronuncia.

Comment: Não é gratis: https://www.mili-mila.com/product-page/cape-verdean-creole-english-dictionary Mas seria possível entrar em contato com o autor.....

Answer (score 1):

deve vir de chico, pois chiqueiro ainda se usa no crioulo, como tchiquero

Comment: Lopes, bem-vindo ao site. Não queres explicar isso melhor. Não sei quanta gente hoje em dia sabe que chiqueiro tem algo a ver com porcos. Tal como está, a tua resposta dá menos informação do que alguns comentários à pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

No Cabo Verde essa palavra, tchuco, significa porco. Algumas das palavras do crioulo cabo-verdiano devem ter origem em outras palavras do português, assim que é provável que a palavra "tchuco" tenha sim relação com o português ou tenha vindo dele.